# Integrating paypal mobile express checkout with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, paypal

Hi i'm creating an app which have shopping cart and payment done via paypal gateway.I tried reading some of documentation under paypal library..but i can't find it...Does any one know simple tutorial or any sample code that is used to integrate paypal gateway in my app.

Comment: Simple google search found this:
http://haifa.baluyos.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=64:objective-c-ios-paypal-integration-tutorial&catid=1:programming&Itemid=5 could be relevant.

Comment: click here for integrating mobile express checkout with iOS [code][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132206/processing-payments-to-users-in-ios/14599035#14599035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can directly go to www.x.com under developers menu select MPL library thats the simple way of integrating paypal in your app..The document attached to that will provide you info abt step by step integration..Follow simple payment method that will be helpful..I hope this answer will help u...